# Recursive listing files in C++ doesn't enter all subdirectories

Tags: c++, linux, list, file, directory

### !!!Solved!!!

Thank you guys for your help, it's all working now. I made changes to my code as suggested by @RSahu and got it to work.
Thanks for all your input I've been really stuck with this.
To @Basile: I will definitely check that out but for this particular piece of code I'm not gonna use it because it looks way too complicated :) But thanks for suggestion.

### Original question

I'm trying to make a C++ code to list all files in given directory and it's subdirectories.

### Quick explanation

Idea is that function `list_dirs(_dir, _files, _current_dir)` will start in top directory and put files into vector `_files` and when it find a directory it will call itself on this directory. The `_current_dir` is there to be prepended to file name if in subdirectory because I need to know the path structure (it's supposed to generate sitemap.xml).
In `list_dirs` there is a call to `list_dir` which simply returns all files in current directory, not making difference between file and directory.

### My problem

What codes does now is that it lists all files in original directory and then all files in one subdirectory but skipping all other subdirectories. It will list them but not the files in them.
And to be even more cryptic, it list files only in this one specific directory and none other. I tried running it in multiple locations but it never went into any other directory.

Thanks in advance and please note that I am beginner at C++ so don't be harsh ;)
LIST_DIR

```
int list_dir(const std::string& dir, std::vector<std::string>& files){
    DIR *dp;
    struct dirent *dirp;
    unsigned fileCount = 0;

    if ((dp = opendir(dir.c_str())) == NULL){
        std::cout << "Error opening dir." << std::endl;
    }

    while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL){
        files.push_back(std::string (dirp->d_name));
        fileCount++;
    }

    closedir(dp);
    return fileCount;
}
```

and LIST_DIRS

```
int list_dirs (const std::string& _dir, std::vector<std::string>& _files, std::string _current_dir){
    std::vector<std::string> __files_or_dirs;

    list_dir(_dir, __files_or_dirs);

    std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = __files_or_dirs.begin();
    struct stat sb;

    while (it != __files_or_dirs.end()){
        if (lstat((&*it)->c_str(), &sb) == 0 && S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)){
            /* how to do this better? */
            if (*it == "." || *it == ".."){
                __files_or_dirs.erase(it);
                continue;
            }

            /* here it should go into sub-directory */
            list_dirs(_dir + *it, _files, _current_dir + *it);

            __files_or_dirs.erase(it);
        } else {
            if (_current_dir.empty()){
                _files.push_back(*it);
            } else {
                _files.push_back(_current_dir + "/" + *it);
            }
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is in the line:

```
if (lstat((&*it)->c_str(), &sb) == 0 && S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)){
```

You are using the name of a directory entry in the call to `lstat`. When the function is dealing with a sub-directory, the entry name does not represent a valid path. You need to use something like:

```
std::string entry = *it;
std::string full_path = _dir + "/" + entry;
if (lstat(full_path.c_str(), &sb) == 0 && S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)){
```

**Suggestions for improvement**

Update `list_dir` so that it doesn't include `"."` or `".."` in the output. It makes sense to me to exclude those files to start with.

```
int list_dir(const std::string& dir, std::vector<std::string>& files){
   DIR *dp;
   struct dirent *dirp;
   unsigned fileCount = 0;

   if ((dp = opendir(dir.c_str())) == NULL){
      std::cout << "Error opening dir." << std::endl;
   }

   while ((dirp = readdir(dp)) != NULL){
      std::string entry = dirp->d_name;
      if ( entry == "." or entry == ".." )
      {
         continue;
      }

      files.push_back(entry);
      fileCount++;
   }

   closedir(dp);
   return fileCount;
}
```

In `list_dirs`, there is no need to erase items from `_files_or_dirs`. The code can be simplified with a `for` loop and by removing the calls to erase items from `_files_or_dirs`.

It's not clear to me what the purpose of `_current_dir` is. Perhaps it can be removed.

Here's an updated version of the function. `_current_dir` is used only to construct the value of the argument in the recursive call.

```
int list_dirs (const std::string& _dir,
               std::vector<std::string>& _files, std::string _current_dir){
   std::vector<std::string> __files_or_dirs;

   list_dir(_dir, __files_or_dirs);

   std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = __files_or_dirs.begin();
   struct stat sb;

   for (; it != __files_or_dirs.end() ; ++it){
      std::string entry = *it;
      std::string full_path = _dir + "/" + entry;

      if (lstat(full_path.c_str(), &sb) == 0 && S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)){
         /* how to do this better? */

         /* here it should go into sub-directory */
         list_dirs(full_path, _files, _current_dir + "/" + entry);

      } else {
         _files.push_back(full_path);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure all of the problems in your code but I can tell you that this line and the other one similar to it are going to cause you problems:

```
__files_or_dirs.erase(it);
```

When you call `erase` you invalidate the iterator and references at or after the point of the erase, including the end() iterator (see this [erase reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase)).  You are calling erase and then not storing the returned iterator and are then looking at it again after this call which is not a good thing to do.  You should at least change the line to this so that you capture the returned iterator which should point to the element just after the erased element (or `end()` if it was the last element)

```
it = __files_or_dirs.erase(it);
```

<s>It also appears from the code you posted that you have a redundancy between `_dir` and `_current_dir`.  You do not modify either of them.  You pass them in as the same value and they stay the same value throughout the function execution.  Unless this is simplified code and you are doing something else, I would recommend you remove the `_current_dir` one and just stick with `_dir`.  You can replace the line in the while loop with `_dir` where you are building the file name and you will have simplified your code which is always a good thing.</s>

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out, I changed my code accordingly and will remember that in the future.

Comment: I can't exactly follow what you suggested in your edit because I need the subdirectories listed in output vector but not the original directory. That's why I need the `_current_dir` parameter. If I use onlz the `_dir` parameter than all files in the orginal dir will have original_dir/filename format which I want only for subdirectories.

Comment: @LukášŠrom -  I see what you are saying, I didn't think about your initial call to the function which would look something like `list_dirs("somedir", files, "");` so `_current_dir` is not equal to `dir`.  I will cross out my edit (sorry, it's late where I am and I didn't think it all the way through).

Answer (score 1):

For this line:

```
   if (lstat((&*it)->c_str(), &sb) == 0 && S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)){
```

Note that `readdir` and consequently `list_dir` only return the file *name*, not the full file path. So at this point `(&*it)->c_str()` only has a file name (e.g. "input.txt"), not the full path, so when you call `lstat` on a file in a subdirectory, the system can't find it.

To fix this, you will need to add in the file path before calling lstat. Something like:

```
   string fullFileName;
   if (dir.empty()){
       fullFileName = *it;
   } else {
       fullFileName = dir + "/" + *it;
   }

   if (lstat(fullFileName.c_str(), &sb) == 0 && S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)){
```

You may have to use `_currentDir` instead of `dir`, depending on what they are actually for (I couldn't follow your explanation).

Answer (score 1):

A simpler way on Linux is to use the [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) function. It is scanning recursively the file tree, and you give it some handler function.